# Doctrine2 PDO Exception Integrity violation 1048 - Fixtures loading - YML

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I've the following entity **Category** defined in YML with bi-directional many-to-many relationship.  When i try to load the fixtures data in the corresponding database via `doctrine:fixtures:load` i receive a **PDO Exception error 1048** about integrity violation that the 'name' field can't be null

```html
# src/tuto/JobeetBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Category.orm.yml
tuto\JobeetBundle\Entity\Category:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: tuto\JobeetBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository
    table: category
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
            unique: true
        slug:
            type: string
            length: 255
            unique: true
    oneToMany:
        jobs:
            targetEntity: Job
            mappedBy: category
    manyToMany:
        affiliates:
            targetEntity: Affiliate
            mappedBy: categories
    lifecycleCallbacks:
        prePersist: [setSlugValue]
        preUpdate: [setSlugValue]
```

```html
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $slug;
public
function setSlug($slug) {
 $this - > slug = $slug;

 return $this;
}

/**
 * Get slug
 *
 * @return string
 */
public
function getSlug() {
 return $this - > slug;
}
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public
function setSlugValue() {
 $sl = new Slugify();
 $this - > slug = $sl - > slugify($this - > getName());
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public
function prePersist() {
 $this - > slug = '';
}
```

May you find the fixture [here](http://pastebin.com/Uucaebsz)

Comment: May we see your fixture(s)?

Comment: updated the question with the link to the fixture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo `$qualityManager` object on line 20:

Here:

```
$qualityManager = new Category();
$technician->setName("Quality Manager");  // <-- Wrong object
```

Try this:

```
$qualityManager = new Category();
$qualityManager->setName("Quality Manager");
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe this typo gave me such trouble ...grrrrr